# Specify index for SELECT statement in Sequel (Ruby ORM)

Tags: ruby, sequel

Is there anything in the Sequel API which allows me to specify an index to use?

The generated SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WITH (INDEX(idx_name))
```

Comment: I think you can add index to your column by using ActiveRecord::Migration.add_index

Comment: I'm using Sequel, not ActiveRecord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequel doesn't have explicit support for that syntax, but you can fake it:

```
DB.from('Users WITH (INDEX(idx_name))'.lit)
```

It's not going to be perfect, though (joins will probably break it).  It's not difficult to modify the adapter to add direct support for that syntax in the DSL, FWIW.